Is this the place where all Downvoted StackOverflow Questions actually get answered?
Tongue in cheek question as my first post, to determine how this community responds in comparison to the crowd at large on StackOverflow...
Is it actually possible to have a sensible discussion in this community?

This isn't a question that can get a useful answer. I hate SO as much as anyone else does - heck, I'm question banned there for a reason unbenknownst to me - but this kind of question is purely subjective, and much too vague to have any kind of authoritative answer.

On behalf of our community, please allow me to welcome you Michael!
Yes, this is a friendly community where people actually help each other and answer questions!
Kindly note that the best place to ask questions like yours is on our "meta" site, which is located here: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com
I've migrated your question to our meta site for you.
I look forward to your contributions here.
A warm welcome to you from the Software Recommendations Stack Exchange!

Somewhat belated answer...
Stack Exchange sites don't do discussions, just questions and answers.  So, to answer your question can we have a sensible discussion - no.
Although there is plenty going on in the chat rooms.  You will get a sensible discussion there.
